# How to change the displayed value of a slider in the matplotlib GUI?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I am building a GUI with matplotlib, and have two sliders which are used to set time values in unix/epoch time. However, this format isn't human-readable, and I would like it to be displayed in [%Y-%m-%d %H:%M] format.

Here's a screenshot of the sliders: [Sliders with epoch time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6T1u.png)

I am using `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(self.slider_start/1e9)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` to convert the epoch value to the desired format. How can I now throw this value onto the GUI?